# Uppercase only the first letter of each word and rest lower

Tags: sed

My file is

```
 cat bla.txt 
AbcDe xYaG
```

need `Abcde Xyzg`

I am using sed 
Didnt work

```
cat bla.txt | sed "s/.*/\L&/g" | sed "s/\w/\u&/"
LAbcDe xYaG
```

Thanks it work

```
perl -pe 's/\w+/\L\u$&/g'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), the simplest and readable solution ;)

```
perl -lne 'print ucfirst for split /\b/, lc' file
```

or :

```
perl -pe 's/\w+/\L\u$&/g'
```

Credits to [Sundeep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4082052/sundeep) for this one

### Output

```
Abcde Xyag
```

### Explanations

```
print()      # do what you think
ucfirst()    # UPPER case the first letter
for()        # perform preceding calls for each element of following list
split(/\b/)  # split string on word boundaries
lc()         # lower-case each element from splited list
```

Comment: `perl -pe 's/\w+/\L\u$&/g'` can also be used

Comment: I prefer readability over complicated and non memorable regex ;) But Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo 'AbcDe xYaG' | sed -E 's/\w+/\L\u&/g'
Abcde Xyag
```

- `-E` to enable ERE
- `\w+` match one or more word characters, since longest match wins, entire words will be matched
- `\L\u&` here `\L` will cause characters to be lowercased, but `\u` will override it and cause first character to be uppercase

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -r -n 's/^([a-zA-Z])(.*)(\s+)([a-zA-Z])(.*)$/\U\1\L\2\3\U\4\L\5/p' file_name
```

Output:

```
Abcde Xyag
```